# ListView not showing contents of BindingCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I've looked at probably a hundred different stack overflow questions/answers and my code is seemingly *exactly* the same as most of the answers, and yet I still cannot get ListView to show anything.

In my `MainWindow.cs` I have

```cs
api = new Api();
            
MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
MainViewModel.Loading = true;
DataContext = MainViewModel;

AttemptLogin();
if (Account.IsLoggedIn){
    api.getAccountDetails();
    
    MainViewModel.GetProfiles(api);
    InitializeComponent();
    
}
```

My `MainViewModel` contains:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Profile> _profiles;
public ObservableCollection<Profile> Profiles => _profiles;

...

public void GetProfiles(Api api){
    _profiles = new ObservableCollection<Profile>(api.getProfiles());
}
```

Within my xaml, I have:

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                Header="Name" />
            
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The API call is:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Profile> getProfiles(){
    var request = new RestRequest("api/benchmarks/results", Method.POST);
    var response = _restClient.Execute(request);
    dynamic test = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
    ObservableCollection<Profile> Profiles = new ObservableCollection<Profile>();
    for (var i = 0; i < test.result.Count; i++){
        Profiles.Add(new Profile(test.result[i]));
    }
    return Profiles;
}
```

I have other properties that show up in the xaml from `MainViewModel` just fine. If I put a breakpoint on `InitializeComponent`, I can see `MainViewModel.Profiles` contains what I would expect it to contain.

[image]

And yet, all I get is the Name header, no contents.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Edit:

If I add `OnPropertyChanged` to the setter for Profile and adjust my viewmodel accordingly:

```cs
...

public ObservableCollection<Profile> Profiles{
    get => _profiles;
    set{
        _profiles = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Profiles");
    }
}

...

public void GetProfiles(Api api){
    Profiles = new ObservableCollection<Profile>(api.getProfiles());
}
```

There is no change.

Comment: Have you tried adding INotifyPropertyChanged on your ViewModel and call OnPropertyChanged event on your setter method of the public property "Profiles" in this case.
Just give a try and check.

Comment: @GK I have indeed. I've updated the question with how I added it. My view model already has `INotifyPropertyChanged` on it as other properties use it without any problems.

Comment: Also, shouldn't using `ObservableCollection` negate the need for `OnPropertyChanged` ? Isn't that one of the main points of using it?

Comment: Can you try setting DataContext after InitializeComponent? "DataContext = MainViewModel;"

Comment: WHEW yep. That was it.

Comment: Also, one more recommendation, try to do all your stuff after InitializeComponent() method. This is general correct practice and you avoid all these minor problems.

Comment: Funny thing is, InitializeComponent was before all of that anyway, certainly outside of the `if` statement. I read in a comment somewhere to try putting all this logic before it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234241/discussion-between-g-k-and-jer-tx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting DataContext after InitializeComponent() method. And one more suggestion, move InitializeComponent() out of if block. Keep always out of conditional blocks and let the UI load on its own and you decide what you wanted to do or show after the page/window is loaded.

Here is the modified code,

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent(); // Keep this as first statement in your View constructor
  // Move below code to some private method and make a call from here. 
  // Just code looks simpler and clean.
  InitializeViewModel();
}

private void InitializeViewModel()
{
  api = new Api();
  MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
  MainViewModel.Loading = true;
  DataContext = MainViewModel;
  AttemptLogin();
  if (Account.IsLoggedIn)
  {
    api.getAccountDetails();
    MainViewModel.GetProfiles(api);
  }
}
```